# Some tutorial for OpenGL ES 2 in Android with NDK?

Tags: android, sdk, gpgpu, opengl-es-2.0, android-ndk

specifically I need to work with the Shading lenguage GLSL. I have already installed NDK, SDK and everything else and is runing ok, i ran an example with openGLES 2 using NDK and it works fine, the problem is that there are many instructions that I dont't undestand. so i need a tutorial or book that teach me that step by step

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you start by reading some of the tutorials on the Khronos site and from the OpenGL Programmers Guide.

I suggest you start with the "Hello Triangle" demo first.

There are two links.

1. [Tutorial on Hello Triangle](http://www.webreference.com/programming/opengl_es/)
2. [Source Code for Hello Triangle](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FWindows%2FChapter_2%2FHello_Triangle) -- Look at Chapter 2

For the good old cube demo, [check this out](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial).

The code is written in WebGL, but you can convert it.

This [site contains all of the downloadable samples](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples) from the Programmer's Guide.  They are pretty good.  They are in the source repository.

I also enjoyed looking through [the "full spec" from the Khronos Site.](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/)

The Shader Language is weird at first -- but you'll grasp it with enough tutorials.